# spring data jpa findBy...... with multi column but the save search text

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i'm using spring data jpa, and have a query to search text from the whole columns.

for example:

> repository.findByNameContainingOrAliasContaining(name, alias, pageable)

And the name and alias are the same value, and i have to write like

> string name = text;   string alias = text;
>   repository.findByNameContainingOrAliasContaining(name, alias,
>   pageable)

and actually, i have 5 columns to be matched, so how can i stop writing the same stupid code ?
and make the code like: `repository.findByNameContainingOrAliasContaining(text, pageable)` (this writing now will cause ".NoSuchElementException")

[image: repository]

Answer (score 4):

When you face a limitation of implicit queries, you can always switch to explicit `@Query`:

```
@Query("select f from Foo f where f.name like %?1% or f.alias like %?1% or ...")
public List<Foo> findByAnyColumnContaining(String text, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: hi,i have tried as you said, but it seems the spring still parsing the method name instead of executing the query annotation. i got exception, "No property any found", how can i fix it, thank you very much!

Comment: It's strange. What if you change the method name to something completely different?

Comment: i tried, for example "fullTextSearch(string text, Pageable pageable)", then the exception shows: "No property full found"....OMG

Comment: Which version of Spring Data JPA do you use? How do you define your repository?

Comment: thanks for your reply. i add a image in my question body. It is my definition of repository, and the version is "1.3.4.RELEASE", i heard there was a bug in version "1.3.1"